# Increasing the call rate automaticallyin SIPp and dump it in CSV file

Tags: sip, export-to-csv, response-time, servlet-container, load-generator

I use this command in sipp for generating load on my SIP servlet container

```
./sipp -sf uac.xml 127.0.0.1:5080 -trace_rtt
```

Two things I need. The first one is increasing the load automatically, for example: add 100 call/second. The second one is the CSV file I get just have response time and time stamp, it does not include the call rate.

Any one can help??

Answer (score 0):

I found the asnwer in SIPp documentation

First problem:

```
-rate_increase 10 -fd 5s
```

this code increases call rate by 10 each 5 seconds.

Second problem:

add this parameter

```
-trace_stat
```

so my command should be like this

```
./sipp -sf uac.xml 127.0.0.1:5080 -trace_rtt -trace_stat -rate_increase 10 -fd 5s
```